# How to convert Javascript string array to float array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Can someone please advise? I need to use C# double array in Javascript. Not sure why it is automatically converting to string array?

Input: `"[0.1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.2]";`

I want output as below:

Output: `[0.1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.2]`

I have tried below. But No luck.

**1.**

```
<% var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();%>
var Output= '<%= serializer.Serialize(Input) %>';
```

**2.**

```
var Output= '<%= serializer.Serialize(Input) %>'.split(',').map(parseFloat)
```

Comment: shouldn't you just... remove th quotes surrounding `<%= ... %>`?

Comment: was getting JS error and the page wasn't rendering if I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse` in javascript :

```
var arr = JSON.parse("[0.1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.2]");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Thanks!.. short and sweet. :)

Comment: Don't think it is working in IE8? Can you please advise?

Comment: You can use jQuery with `jQuery.parseJSON("[0.1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.2]");`